# Ant calling taskkill on out of memory

Tags: java, xml, memory, ant

I am having trouble adding the

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /F /PID %%p"
```

argument to a java command in ant.

When I add

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /F /PID %%p""/>
```

or

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\\"taskkill /F /PID %%p\\""/>
```

Ant fails to parse the XML file.

If I do this

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=&quot;taskkill /F /PID %%p&quot;"/>
```

Then i get

```
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .F
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Anyone know the correct way to do this so that the JVM gets the correct args?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML allows single quotes for argument values:

```
<jvmarg value='-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"taskkill /F /PID %%p\"'/>
```

This will correct the xml syntax problem of the build file.

---

Edited the line of code above. From a [post in a different forum](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=105960015500751&w=1) I learned, that the quotes have to be escaped, otherwise it leads to the "ClassNotFoundException" that you encountered  too.

Comment: I get the same NoClassDefFoundError when using this too

Comment: Great this passes the quotes through.  :)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick test of creating an out of memory, the quotes actually aren't needed :)

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p"/>
```

I've been stuck on this for hours and never actually tested it without the quotes.

It turns out that the special is for bat files which do need the quotes, like this

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /F /PID %%p"
```